# How to configure vee-validate globally in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vee-validate

My question, is there a way we could create a one .js file and state all `extend(s)`? so we don't need to extend each time we use the validator.

I just ask because my codes becomes lengthy each time I need a validator. I need to extend it first to be usable.

---

I'm currently using **vue** & **vuetify** with [vee-validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate). The below codes are working fine [reference](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#vee-validate).

**template**

```
<ValidationObserver ref="observer" v-slot="{ validate, reset }">
    <ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" name="Name" rules="required|max:10">
        <v-text-field v-model="user.name" :error-messages="errors" label="Name" type="text"></v-text-field>
    </ValidationProvider>
</ValidationObserver>
```

**script**

```
import { confirmed, required, email, max } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";
import { extend, ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, setInteractionMode } from "vee-validate";

setInteractionMode("eager");

extend("required", {
  ...required,
  message: "{_field_} can not be empty",
});

extend("confirmed", {
  params: ["target"],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    return value === target;
  },
  message: "{_field_} does not match",
});

extend("max", {
  ...max,
  message: "{_field_} may not be greater than {length} characters",
});

extend("email", {
  ...email,
  message: "Email must be valid",
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can declare all your configuration in one file, then import that into your main.js. So, you'd have

```
// validationConfig.js

import { confirmed, required, email, max } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

extend()
extend()
//etc
```

In main:

```
// main.js

import path/to/validationConfig
```

Comment: You can still use the same template, just reference your rules by name and the global configuration should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use mixins ([vuejs 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), [vuejs 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html#mixins)). A mixin object can contain any component options. You can also apply a mixin globally.